# Проблема выхода написанного приложения в Интернет

Tags: windows, restsharp

проблема состоит в том что у некоторых клиентов моего прилоежения возникает проблема с доступом в интернет. В пробую запустить тот же ресурс (php cкрипт) в браузере - все работает, но как только пытаюсь получить ту же информацию в приложении просто долго грузит и ошибка TimeOut. Подскажите в чем может быть проблема?

У пользователя одного брандмауэр полностью отключал - не помогло: [image: Брандмауэр отключен]

Также уже добавлял приложение в белый список исходящих и входящих подключений - такая же проблема. Уже просто руки опускаются от безисходности

Comment: Проблем может быть уйма, от блокировкой конкретного адреса провайдером, до отсутствия у клиента например, нужных компонентов шифрования. К примеру на старых OS версия TLS не соответствуем реальным стандартам, из-за чего соединения может не быть. В любом случае, на данный вопрос невозможно ответить, ибо мы даже кода не видим. И да, при чем тут RestSharp (библиотека для C# (csharp)) я так и не понял...